# Statistics on those who completed prison term by country

Tags: rule-of-law

I wonder if there is any statistics by country on the percent of population that have completed a prison sentence or were sentenced.

So far I only found statistics on the percentage of currently imprisoned, but this depends on average term which varies by country.

Comment: Did you find anything in self-research since Nov 6? The info seems interesting.

Comment: @LateralFractal  no

Comment: Pity. I might have a crack at this one later.

Comment: @LateralFractal I am quite sure the percent would be highest for Russia. The US leads by the percent of currently imprisoned, but this is because they give incredible prison terms.

Comment: Do you have any statistics for Russia? I suspect USA would be in the leadership, because they imprison for minor offences, like drug abuse. But such raw statistics wouldn't be useful per se, they don't say if the criminality rate is high in the given country, or the given country is very 'generous' with serving imprisonments.

Comment: Just a side note, from what I know in Poland many people who are either homeless or live in the poor conditions commit minor criminal offences to spend winter in warm prison, where they additionally get food every day.

Comment: You might want to consider a search for people with criminal record. There are a great number of hits for the US. It could lead you somewhere.

Comment: I suspect that you could find most of the information you are looking for here: http://www.amnestyusa.org/research

They are also pretty good about helping assemble data if you have a reason that aligns with their cause.  If its just curiosity then you will probably have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For the United States [this Department of Justice report](http://bjs.gov/content/pub/pdf/Llgsfp.pdf) details how likely it is for someone to go to prison during their lifetime by age, race and gender. The report says that:

> An estimated 5.1% of all persons in the United States will be confined in a State or Federal prison during their lifetime.

As for the rest of the world, it's hard to say but that should get you somewhere.